# Python test datetime object if it is in the past present or future

Tags: python, datetime

in python, if I have a date string in the following format `yyyy-mm-dd`, I would like to write a function to check if the date is in the past, present or future. However, I am having some trouble with this. I have written the following code...

```
from datetime import datetime

def check_date(date_string):
    this_date = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d')
    now = datetime.today()
    if this_date < now:
        print("the date is in the past")
    elif this_date > now:
        print("the day is in the future")
    else:
        print("the day is today")
```

however, when I tested this, it gives me...

```
>>check_date('2022-08-08')
the date is in the past
>>check_date('2022-10-10')
the day is in the future
>>check_date('2022-09-22') #this is todays date
the date is in the past
```

I'm not sure why it is giving this unexpected behaviour.
thanks

Comment: the problem is because of the time part of datetime

Comment: `datetime.today()` also gets the time so something like `2022-09-22 02:30:00.000000` is returned. Try stripping the time from `now` as well.

Comment: so, when i do that i get an error saying ```TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'``` i think this is because once you strip the time using ```strftime``` it converts the datetime object to a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this!

```py
from datetime import datetime

def check_date(date_string):
    this_date = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    now = datetime.today().date()
    print(now, this_date)
    if this_date < now:
        print("the date is in the past")
    elif this_date > now:
        print("the day is in the future")
    else:
        print("the day is today")
```

Answer (score 3):

`datetime.datetime.today()` includes both date and time, as a quick debug print would have shown.  Use this:

```
import datetime

def check_date(date_string):
    this_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d')
    now = datetime.date.today()
...
```

Comment: thanks! however, when i do that, i get the following error ```TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is where you get the today's date. `datetime.today()` create an instance which includes hours, minutes, seconds in addition to year, month, day. However, you are trying to compare them with date only (i.e., year, month, day format.

If you consider `date.today()` instead of `datetime.today()`, you should be good to go.

Comment: The more succinct solution

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
year = 2022
month = 9
day = 22
Date_to_check = datetime.date(datetime(year,month,day))
current_day = datetime.date(datetime.now())

if Date_to_check == current_day:
    print("it is present")
elif Date_to_check > current_day:
    print("it is future")
else:
    print("it is past")
```

please review this code and you'll get some idea how it is working.